# HighCharts Stock Chart fire event on chart redraw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using the [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) stock charting library to generate a basic OHLC stock chart.  I want to perform some action when the chart is generated (and after it's regenerated by changing the displayed time frame).  I'm trying to do this using the `plotOptions.ohlc.events.show` event ([documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#plotOptions-ohlc-events--show)).

The problem I'm having is the even isn't firing at all.  If I follow the [example for the click event](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-events-click/), the alert fires correctly when I click the series.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'divChart',
        height: 450
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 2
    },

    xAxis: {
        maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000
    },

    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'OHLC'
        },
        height: 200,
        lineWidth: 2
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        },
        top: 250,
        height: 100,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],

    title: {
        text: 'Stock Chart'
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'ohlc',
        name: 'Prices',
        id: 'prices',
        data: ohlc
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1
    }],

    // The event I am trying to bind to
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                show: function () {
                    alert("show");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

- Is this the correct way to fire an event when the chart is redrawn?
- If so, why isn't the event firing, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the chart part to something similar

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            redraw: function(){   // or load - refer to API documentation
             alert('Chart Loaded');   
            }
        }
    },
```

They've got a nice API browser - might come in handy 
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-events--load

Comment: Thanks.  I was on the right track, just missed the redraw event.